# How to add an input field below date inside angular malarial calendar

Tags: angular-material, calendar, angular12

I'm trying to implement scheduler events with an angular material calendar, I want to add an event to the dates and I need something like below in the picture  [image]

There should be an option to edit and delete also when I click on the date below input option should be shown to give the values of an event. The screenshot is an example of a full-calendar. But I'm looking for an Angular material option.

Any help would be great

Thanks in Advance!